# Android - Canvas onDraw with zoomed camara following character movements

Tags: java, android, camera, android-canvas

Some Context:

I am creating an Android game which draws a maze onto a canvas against a background image, this uses a square block and therefore the maze is always automtically zoomed in to a 5 x 5 square, of a maze that may be 20 x 20. The maze is drawn by simply running through a set of for loops and then drawing lines in the relevent places. This is all working perfectly, however I am having an issue with getting my onDraw to work smoothly. This is occuring due to the fact that everytime I invalidate I have to re-run the for look and run various if statements to check positions (unfortunetly this process cannot be improved).

The Question:

I am looking to re-write the way my maze is drawn onto the canvas, below are the 3 main features I need to implement:

1 - Draw the whole maze onto the canvas (this is easy enough)
2 - Zoom in on the maze so only a 5 x 5 is shown
3 - Move the character (who is always centered on the screen) and draw the next seciton of the maze

Now as mentioned above drawing the whole maze is easy enough and will make the onDraw signifcatly quicker as their is no need to run the for loop on invaldate, it can be done once when the level is first loaded up.

In terms of point 2 & 3, the way I see this working is the charcacter to be drawn in the middle of the canvas then a 2d birdseye view camera to be attached / linked to the characters movement. This camera would also need to be zoomed in to an extent that it only displays a 5 x 5 of the overall maze grid. Then as the charcater moves the camera moves with the character and displays the next section of the maze which has already been drawn. I have tried a few things and done some reasearch however I have never worked with canvas before and no idea really where to start and if this is even possible.

So to sum up the main part of the question is whether their is a way to link a birdseye view camera to a character which is zoomed in and moves with the character image.

Below is a snippet as to how the maze is currently drawn, using 2 sets of for loops checking against 2 sets of boolean arrays[][], which simply store the vertical and horixaonl lines to be drawn.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, 100, background);
    RectBackground.set(0,0, FullScreenWidth, FullScreenWidth);
    canvas.drawBitmap(gameBackground, null, RectBackground, null);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            float x = j * totalCellWidth;
            float y = i * totalCellHeight;

            indexY = i + currentY;
            indexX = j + currentX;

            // Draw Verticle line (y axis)
            if (indexY < vLength && indexX < vLines[indexY].length && vLines[indexY][indexX])
            {
                RectOuterBackground.set((int)x + (int)cellWidth, (int)y, (int)x + (int)cellWidth + 15,  (int)y + (int)cellHeight + 15);
                canvas.drawBitmap(walls, null, RectOuterBackground, null);
            }
            // Draws Horizontal lines (x axis)
            if (indexY < hLength && indexX < hLines[indexY].length && hLines[indexY][indexX])
            {
                RectOuterBackground.set((int)x, (int)y + (int)cellHeight,(int)x + (int)cellWidth + 15,(int)y + (int)cellHeight + 15);
                canvas.drawBitmap(walls, null, RectOuterBackground, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the drawing faster, you can double buffer the canvas by drawing directly into a bitmap and flashing the bitmap into the canvas like this. It's very fast.

```
private void init()
{
        //variables below are class-wide variables
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(cwidth, cheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        bitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        bitmapPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        myPaint.setColor(0xff000000);
        myCanvas = new Canvas(b);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    super.onDraw(c);
    c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, myPaint);

    for(int i = 0; i < number lines; i++)
    {
        //draw here using myPath
    }

    if(b != null)
        c.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, myPaint);

    myCanvas.drawPath(myPath, bitmapPaint);

}
```

Then, to "move around" I would suggest using a crop box. What this means is that a 1:1 scale, the image is larger than the viewport displayed on the screen. Really what's happening when someone "moves" is the bitmap is being moved beneath the crop box.

You could use BitmapRegionDecoder and display only the region the character is in (this might be slowish) or by using

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

The src parameter here allows you to specify a small region of the bitmap to display. It is effectively a crop box.

Comment: I should also add that the onDraw method is woefully incomplete. If you need to see the whole thing working, I can send you some code. I've written an app that does something similar to what you're doing with the maze. It draws notebook lines and captures handwriting from a stylus.

Comment: I will have a look at this tomorrow, could you please email me your complete code so I can look at a working version. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how to email people through SO. How does one do that?

Comment: Just click on my username and get the details from there and then send the email from any external account.

Comment: Can you send me your sample code for this please to llpartners2012@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

To zoom in and out you need to multiply the coordinates by a number( zoom factor)

```
int x1 = (int)x + (int)cellWidth; 
int y1 = (int)y; 
int x2 = (int)x + (int)cellWidth + 15;  
int y2 = (int)y + (int)cellHeight + 15;

RectOuterBackground.set(x1*zoom, y1*zoom, x2*zoom, y2*zoom);
```

note that zoom must be a floating point number, using zoom=2 that makes everything twice as big.

if you want to put the camera on top of the cell (xc, yc) you need to do this:

```
RectOuterBackground.set( (x1-xc)*zoom, (y1-yc)*zoom, (x2-xc)*zoom, (y2-yc)*zoom);
```

Try first drawing the whole maze, and soon you will figure out how to only draw the bit of the maze that is only inside the screen

I hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: I will have a look at this at some stage tonight and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide me with a more complete snippet of your code, as not 100% sure how to implement it. E.g are the int not meant to have ; at the end. So far I have drawn my complete maze 10 x 10, now I need to implement the zoom with camera so it moves smoothly (gradually displaying the next sections of the maze). Thanks

Comment: Can you send me what you have so far? I'll implement this bit for you

Comment: Hi, here is my complete onDraw, this draws the background images and lines for my maze. Along with the character and his movement (character is a sprite image), http://pastebin.com/YL9utzpe Thanks